# Написание имени "Ф. фон-Лист"

Tags: орфография, ономастика

Правильно ли написано: "Ф. фон-Лист"?

Answer (score 1):

Пишите **без дефиса**. А ещё вот Вам информация из ***ПАС Лопатина***:

Служебные слова (артикли, предлоги и др.) ван, да, дас, де, делла, дель, дер, ди, дос, дю, ла, ле, фон и т. п., входящие в состав западноевропейских и южноамериканских фамилий, пишутся со строчной буквы, например: Людвиг ван Бетховен, Леонардо да Винчи, Оноре де Бальзак, Лопе де Вега, Альфред де Мюссе, Хуана Инес де ла Крус, Лукка делла Роббиа, Андреа дель Сарто, Роже Мартен дю Гар, Женни фон Вестфален, Макс фон дер Грюн, Жанна д'Арк; Ортега-и-Гассет, Риего-и-Нуньес.

*Примечание 1*. В некоторых личных именах служебные слова традиционно пишутся с прописной буквы (как правило, если прописная пишется в языке-источнике), напр.: Ван Гог, Д'Аламбер, Шарль Де Костер, Эдуардо Де Филиппо, Ди Витторио, Этьен Ла Боэси, Анри Луи Ле Шателье, Ле Корбюзье, Эль Греко, Дос Пассос.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, конечно. Пишется без дефиса. Проверить легко, на [википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82,_%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD)